# mean - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, mean

I have:

```
A_prev = np.random.randn(2, 4, 4, 3)
...
a_prev_slice =  np.array(A_prev[vert_start:vert_end,horiz_start:horiz_end,:])
print("a_prev_slice.shape: "+str(a_prev_slice.shape))
print("np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3)).shape: "+str(np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3)).shape))
    ...
A[i, h, w, c] = np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3))
```

this prints out:

```
a_prev_slice.shape: (2, 2, 4, 3)
np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3)).shape: (2, 2)
```

and fails with:

```
---> 53                         A[i, h, w, c] = np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3))
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

doc for [mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) says it can take a tuple of ints, so I am lost.

edit: i need to specify more subscripts when i do the slice and axis is not required.

Comment: Try printing out a_prev_slice and the result of the np.mean function. I assume that np.mean is returning an array with those parameters rather than a single value.

Comment: First of all, check `np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3)).shape`. Does it correspond with the shape you expect? It doesn't, it's actually a NumPy _array_ with more than one value. This is why Python tells you that you're "setting an array element with a sequence".

Comment: strange: a_prev_slice.shape: (2, 2, 4, 3)
np.mean(a_prev_slice,axis=(2,3)).shape: (2, 2) so maybe it is the assigment statement?

Comment: @RayTayek, `axis=(2,3)` tells `np.mean` to compute the mean over these two axes, which, given that your array is 4D, will return an array of more than one dimension anyway, while you want only a number because `A[i, h, w, c]` is a number. This means you should _probably_ just use `a_prev_slice.mean()`, but this depends on what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: i suspect that you are correct. my slice probably needs more definite subscripts. thanks

Comment: force, post and answer and i will check it. thanks